# changing content of p element using innerHTML

Tags: javascript

I have the following script:

```
var before = document.getElementById('before');    
if (switchElement.value == 'single'){
    for (var i=0; i < before.length; i++) {
        if (before[i].id == "before_label") {
            before[i].innerHTML = 'Image';
            break;
        }
    }
    after.style.display = 'none';   
}
```

and the HTML looks like:

```
<div id="before">
    <p id="before_label"> Before Image: </p>
    <input type="file" name="before"  size="40">
    <input type="hidden" name="MAX_FILE_SIZE" value="10000000">
</div>
```

Was wondering why it didn't work and change the inner html to change?

Comment: Do you have just one or many "before" divs?

Comment: I believe adit has only one. I think the misconception here is that you need to loop though the "before" div to access its children.

Comment: @karim79: i'd say the code is wrong. even if he has more than one `before` the GEBId returns only one.

Comment: @adit: could you elaborate moreand  show some more code and markup? probably a fiddle too.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

To access the `innerHTML` of `before_label`, just access it directly:

```
document.getElementById('before_label').innerHTML = 'Image';
```

Comment: kind of a stupid question, but what if I don't have it enclosed in any html tag? is there a way to modify it? the issue is that with a <p> it gives me an extra break/new line

Comment: You can always wrap what you're trying to select with `<span>` tags. So `<span id='myelem'>Some text</span>`.

Answer (score 0):

getElementById only returns one element. You need to acces the child objects via childNodes.

Try this:

```
var before = document.getElementById('before').childNodes;    
if (switchElement.value == 'single'){
    for (var i=0; i < before.length; i++) {
        if (before[i].id == "before_label") {
            before[i].innerHTML = 'Image';
            break;
        }
    }
    after.style.display = 'none';   
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Why the for loop? Just get the element by its id:

```
var before_label = document.getElementById('before_label');
if (switchElement.value == 'single') {
    before_label.innerHTML = 'Image';
    after.style.display = 'none';
}
```